# Pattern binding the same variable to different types sharing a trait

Tags: rust, pattern-matching, traits

I have a question about pattern matching on values sharing some behaviour through a trait.

I have an enum with two variants, each binding value of different types, where both types implement a trait. I'm trying to figure out whether it's possible to create a single pattern (of the `E::VarA(x) | E::VarB(x)` form) in which I bind both types to a single constant, provided I'm only interested in using the shared behaviour.

An illustrative example: [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=e478ab33ee5b680fe7162aa6a6102275):

```
trait T {
    fn f(&self) -> usize;
}

struct A;

impl T for A {
    fn f(&self) -> usize { 1 }
}

struct B;

impl T for B {
    fn f(&self) -> usize { 2 }
}

enum E {
    VarA(A),
    VarB(B),
}

fn unwrap(e: E) -> usize {
    match e {
        E::VarA(v) | E::VarB(v) => T::f(&v)
    }
}

fn main() {
    let val = E::VarA(A{});  
    println!("{}", unwrap(val));
}
```

The code obviously does not compile, but it shows my intentions. Is there a way to make the code work, preferably more elegant than simply splitting the `pat1 | pat2 => ...` into `pat1 => ... ; pat2 => ...` ?

Comment: Splitting the match into separate arms is pretty much the way to go. A variable binding must have a fixed type; it can't be all of the possible types simultaneously.

Answer (score 3):

You can make a macro that unwraps to match statement.

```
trait T {
    fn f(&self) -> usize;
}

struct A;
impl T for A {
    fn f(&self) -> usize { 1 }
}

struct B;
impl T for B {
    fn f(&self) -> usize { 2 }
}

enum E {
    VarA(A),
    VarB(B),
}

macro_rules! unwrap {
    ($value:expr, $pattern:pat => $result:expr) => {
        match $value {
            E::VarA($pattern) => $result,
            E::VarB($pattern) => $result,
        }
    };
}

fn main() {
    let a = E::VarA(A{});
    let b = E::VarB(B{});

    println!("a:{} b:{}",
        unwrap!(a, ref sm => sm.f()),
        unwrap!(b, ref sm => sm.f()));

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If all variants implement this trait, the best solution is to implement the trait for the whole enum ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=6248acd50873c8b1a69e087972fe3429)).

Relevant code:

```
impl T for E {
    fn f(&self) -> usize {
        match self {
            E::VarA(x) => x.f(),
            E::VarB(x) => x.f(),
        }
    }
}
```