# Can I match on all enum variants that have the same shape of their values?

Tags: enums, rust, pattern-matching

I have an enum:

```rust
enum MyEnum {
    A(i32),
    B(i32),
    C,
    D,
    // ...
}
```

Can I match on `A` and `B` simultaneously with something like this:

```rust
let a = MyEnum::A(1);
match a {
    _(n) => { // do something for all variants which have one i32 value
    }
    _ => { // ignore the rest
    }
};
```

Is there any way to accomplish this? Do I have to match all the variants and apply the same "body" for each?

Comment: If you don't care about real type why not merge A and B ?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**No**, your desired syntax is not possible; I don't know how that syntax could work if you had multiple variants with the same count of fields with differing types:

```
enum MyEnum {
    A(bool),
    B(String),
}
```

> Do I have to match all the variants and apply the same "body" for each?

Yes, but you can use patterns to match them in a single match arm:

```rust
match a {
    MyEnum::A(n) | MyEnum::B(n) => {
        // use `n`
    }
    _ => {}
};
```

Or the equivalent `if let`:

```rust
if let MyEnum::A(n) | MyEnum::B(n) = a {
    // use `n`
}
```

Comment: I was hoping that rust's type inference system would be powerful enough. But I guess this will work just fine.

Comment: You can create a macro that unwraps to match statement and calls arbitrary functions.            like: unwrap!(a, ref sm => sm.f()). See this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60346796/pattern-binding-the-same-variable-to-different-types-sharing-a-trait/60347183#60347183

Comment: I wonder why this answer is accepted, this just does not work and results in error `error[E0308]: mismatched types`

Comment: @mirind4 [works fine](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=f45578b9123f4d44ced6c1e876bdc5a1).

Comment: @Shepmaster, ah sorry, my bad, it did not work with the enum with different types.

Comment: @mirind4 yeah, that’s why the first paragraph states “No, your desired syntax is not possible […] if you had multiple types”.

Comment: This answer should be clearer that the code won't work for enums with different variant types