# Destructure rust enum without matching

Tags: rust, enums, destructuring

What would be the correct way to simplify this strange code? There is no variant of `AstNode` that doesn't wrap around an inner structure.

```
impl<'a> Debug for AstNode<'a> {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut std::fmt::Formatter<'_>) -> std::fmt::Result {
        match self {
            AstNode::Literal(inner) => inner.fmt(f),
            AstNode::Variable(inner) => inner.fmt(f),
            AstNode::Binary(inner) => inner.fmt(f),
            AstNode::Unary(inner) => inner.fmt(f),
            AstNode::Call(inner) => inner.fmt(f),
            AstNode::Function(inner) => inner.fmt(f),
            AstNode::If(inner) => inner.fmt(f),
            AstNode::While(inner) => inner.fmt(f),
            AstNode::Begin(inner) => inner.fmt(f),
            AstNode::Assign(inner) => inner.fmt(f),
            AstNode::NewGlobal(inner) => inner.fmt(f),
            AstNode::Error(inner) => inner.fmt(f),
            AstNode::TestAssert(inner) => inner.fmt(f),
            AstNode::TestExpect(inner) => inner.fmt(f),
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: My recommendation: leave it. But if you must: If all the `inner`s are of the same type, you could rearrange to `struct AstNode { inner: InnerType, typ: AstNodeType } enum AstNodeType { Literal, Variable, … }`. If they have differing types, you could use `inner: Box<dyn InnerType>`, or [enum_dispatch](https://docs.rs/enum_dispatch/latest/enum_dispatch/) (which magics similar behavior up through macros). Though, why not just use `#[derive(Debug)]`?

Comment: @Caesar `#[derive(Debug)]` will add the enum name.

Comment: I know. But I wonder if it's undesirable.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Yeah, I'm trying to hide it. I looked into enum_dispatch, but I figured it might be best to write everything out myself first, plus none of these enums are known at compile time so it probably won't benefit from the huge optimizations they promise.

Comment: A relative post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60379893/can-i-match-on-all-enum-variants-that-have-the-same-shape-of-their-values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `inner` member is not dependent on enum variant there is no need to put it in enum. You can promote it up, so there will be no need to match it. Something along those lines:

```rust
struct AstNode(AstKind, InnerType);

enum AstKind {
  Literal,
  Variable,
  ...
}
```

then you can write:

```rust
impl<'a> Debug for AstNode<'a> {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut std::fmt::Formatter<'_>) -> std::fmt::Result {
        self.1.fmt(f)
    }
}
```

This type system explicitly states that `InnerType` and `AstKind` is independent. Which is your case If I understand correctly.

Comment: This is great and would work nicely. Unfortunately in my case it won't be worth refactoring everything else but this is probably the best solution. Thanks!